# How to define XAML sample data for [] properties

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to use XAML sample data where my 'item' class uses a form of dynamic properties by defining a property accessor for `[]`.  It (`PremiseObject`) does so like this:

```
...
/// <summary>
/// Property accessor. Simulates a dynamic object.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public object this[string name] {
    get {
        PremiseProperty prop;
        if (_properties.TryGetValue(name, out prop))
            return prop.Value;

        // In XAML <Button Content="Trigger" Command="{Binding [TriggerCommand]}">
        // where 'Trigger' is the name of hte property that is momentary
        if (name.EndsWith("Command")) {
            string cmd = name.Substring(0, name.Length - "Command".Length);
            if (_properties.TryGetValue(cmd, out prop)) {
                return new PremiseCommand(this, cmd);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    set {
        SetMember(name, value);
    }
}
...
```

Never mind the goop in the middle. The key thing is that in my XAML I can do cool stuff like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="DoorsListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,35">
                <StackPanel>
                    <!-- We use Description instead of DisplayName because DisplayName changes for GDOs. -->
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="320"
                               Text="{Binding [Description]}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}"
                                />
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="320"
                               Text="{Binding [GarageDoorStatus], Converter={StaticResource GDOStateFormatConverter}}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"

                               Foreground="{Binding [GarageDoorStatus], Converter={StaticResource GDOStateColorConverter}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button DataContext="{Binding}" 
                        Content="Trigger" 
                        IsEnabled="True"
                        Style="{StaticResource GDOButtonStyle}"
                        Command="{Binding [TriggerCommand]}">
                </Button>

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I'm super happy with the way this works. I've tried several forms of dynamic objects and until I've hit THIS problem, it's been working fantastic.

THIS problem is I have no idea how to specify sample XAML data for this.

```
<vm:GarageDoorsViewModel
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PremiseWP.ViewModels"
    xmlns:prem="clr-namespace:PremiseWebClient"
    IsDataLoaded="False">

    <vm:GarageDoorsViewModel.Items>
        <prem:PremiseObject *** SOMETHING GOES HERE ***/>
    </vm:GarageDoorsViewModel.Items>

</vm:GarageDoorsViewModel>
```

I need some syntax for specifying the sample data that says "this is a dynamic property with this name and this value".

How would I do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but I guess you need set ContentPropertyAttribute for your class. And than put your values to content of tag.

```
<vm:GarageDoorsViewModel.Items>
    <prem:PremiseObject>
        <object x:Key="key"/>
    </prem:PremiseObject>
</vm:GarageDoorsViewModel.Items>
```

Comment: This gets me part way there; I can almost get it to work, but I've decided the re-factoring of my library that will be required will not be worth it. Instead I'm changing strategy and will use `d:DesignInstance` instead of `d:DesignData` and supply my sample data via code. Thanks for your help.